# Find WordPress site in anther domain without do this

Tags: wordpress, security, wordpress-rest-api

I have WordPress website and use domain after publish on domain x. I find that work good on x.com but find same design and pages on api.y.com.

I need solve this problem. how it is on another domain if i not publish on it and y.com this website work for company.